# Rails ActiveAdmin - after creating a post I wish to render an action

Tags: activeadmin

I'd like to know how can I render an action after creating a post on ActiveAdmin. My idea is after I create a post I'd like to get it's tags. I searched all over internet and there's not sufficient documentation.

I just saw that I can override the create action, but now I get a missing template error, can someone post some example code for overriding create in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Post model:

```
after_create :get_tags


def get_tags
  tags = Post.find(:last)
  tags = tags.tag
  # return values
  self.get_tags
end
```

Answer (score 4):

In your AA definition:

```
controller do
    def create
        # Do your stuff
        # You can try one of this:
        # render :action => :show
        # render "path/to/template" , :layout => "active_admin"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Not big fan of rails model callbacks I would recomend using active admin controller callbacks in this case.

```
controller do
  after_create :get_tags

  def get_tags(post)
    post.get_tags
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue a few days ago, the way I solved it was like this.

***in your model***

```
after_create :method_name

def method_name
   whatever you need to do
end
```

Be careful that if you are going to update attributes in the DB to use:

```
model.update_attributes(:attribute_name => new_value)
```

and not

```
model.save!
```

I spent a few days until I found out that save doesn't work.